# Как написать такое регулярное выражение на Javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка.

> GE98BG0000000123456789

```
Первые четыре символа должны быть: [A-Za-z-0-9] 'GE98'
После четырех символов должно два символа: [A-Za-z] 'BG' или 'AB'
После должно быть шестнадцать цифр: '0000000123456789'
```

Comment: осталось добавить только кол-ва символов

Comment: не получается собрать все вместе

Comment: `^[A-Za-z-0-9]{4}(BG|AB)\d{16}$` это если брать в условие `'BG' или 'AB'`

Comment: Если использовать `var rx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{16}$/`, то результатом `rx.test(s)` будет  `true`. Это надо или что-то другое? Заметьте, `[A-Za-z-0-9]`, в отличие от `[A-Za-z0-9]`, также находит знак `-`. Я так понимаю, у вас опечатка, да? Или `----BG0000000123456789` должно соответствовать условию?

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
var rx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{16}$/;
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{4}` - 4 буквы или цифры ASCII
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` - две буквы ASCII
- `\d{16}` - шестнадцать цифр ASCII
- `$` - конец  строки.

JS-код:

```js
var s = "GE98BG0000000123456789";
var rx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{16}$/;
console.log( rx.test(s) ); // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z-0-9]{4}(?:BG|AB)\d{16}$
```